# После редактирования Resources\Strings.resx в Visual Studio появляется лишний Strings1.Designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, русификация

После редактирования Resources\Strings.resx в Visual Studio появляется лишний Strings1.Designer.cs

```
Resources\
    Strings.resx

        Strings.Designer.cs

        Strings1.Designer.cs
```

После этого проект не запускается.

Приходится каждый раз после редактирования перевода Strings.resx удалять
    Strings1.Designer.cs.

В чём проблема?

При это происходит создание второй Compile Include

```
   <Compile Include="Resources\Strings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Strings.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Resources\Strings1.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Strings.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>

<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Strings.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Strings1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ручное редактирование вне Visual Studio или через редактор Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что содержится в файле проекта (.csproj)

Если в теге LastGenOutput указано Resources1, например, так:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

То уберите единицу:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```